# ASP.NET MVC Server File Browsers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

On my current project we would like to expose some server directories to the client so they can control their own assets/static HTML/CSS etc. The existing web forms project is being replaced by MVC and I am struggling to find an out of the box server file browser with which to expose this functionality.

Here is an example for WebForms: [Telerik FileExplorer demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx)

Can anyone recommend a decent alternative which is designed for the MVC framework? We don't mind paying license fees, however something extensible and preferably open source would be better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for some jQuery,Ajax based file managers

some links to start with

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SFBrowser

http://riderdesign.com/articles/Build-a-file-tree-explorer-with-jQuery-and-ASP.NET.aspx

Comment: Cool, these look good! Will keep the question open for a little while to see if anything else comes up

Comment: the links are down ;(

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery File Tree](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) works well for me.

It is read-only and you can set root directory and other options.

It has an ASPX connector included in package.

Answer (score 1):

*[Full Disclosure: I work for Telerik.]*

Telerik has not yet recreated the RadFileExplorer reusable UI experience for MVC, but we do have a powerful Treeview in our open source Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC. Using the Treeview, you can easily create a server file explorer using techniques similar to those in the RiderDesign article highlighted by Ajay. One advantage of using the Telerik Extensions vs. something like a JavaScript UI plug-in is that you get server and client-side rendering, improving your application's accessibility and behavior in non-JS clients.

You can learn more about using the Treeview in these online examples:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/TreeView

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Todd. I am already using the Telerik MVC controls (Tree and Grid) and this would have been my fallback if I could not get something off the shelf. Are you by any chance planning on creating an MVC file manager (or willing to accept a patch ;))?

Comment: Wow ! How do I setup the tree view from the controller instead of using a billion java script lines on the view? ie- get list of folder and a for each using each one?